# how can a program keep a secret from its creator?

Tags: security

The idea is that I want a program that can edit a file yet I, the programmer, cannot edit or forge the file. Encrypting the file is an obvious choice, but even then, I'll still have to keep the encryption key secret from myself somehow.

Obscuring the secret doesn't seem to work, because I could just use the de-obscuring part of the code that I would need for the program.

I'm asking this because I'm trying to make a program that will keep me productive by monitoring my activities, and tell my friends/boss/family just how terrible a procrastinator i am if i don't live up to the goals i set the previous day (in other words: Present me can force future me to not procrastinate)

Comment: This question is awesome (the central concept, if not the reason for implementation); I'm not entirely sure it's on-topic here, but I have no better suggestions for where it should go.

Comment: Well... I think programmers would be better.

Comment: @DavidThomas Why, thank you. And yes, I admit that it's a little out of place, but likewise I have no idea of where to put it.

Comment: Is your question about insight into the program's activities or ensuring that the program can't be modified? To store data that can't be read asymmetric cryptography is the way to go, e.g. save logs encrypted with a public RSA keys whose private key counterpart is only know to other people. In order to prevent yourself from modifying the program you need some computer where you have no administrative (aka root) access. Otherwise you'll always be able to stop/change it.

Comment: @DanielBöhmer The question is about the user&creator being unable to forge the productivity-report. Problem is that I need root access to do my work. It doesn't matter if I could change the program or file, as long as it isn't easy (because just doing my work would be the path of less resistance then). Saving the logs separately with RSA public key and giving the private key to the person who is to read the report is a good idea, but i could still delete and forge the log

Comment: What keeps (future) you from just turning off the program that monitors you?

Comment: @Segfault This is exactly why I want to write a program like this - I can easily disable website blockers and programs like those. That's why I want to be unable to forge the logs. If there are no logs, then the report will default to say that I was procrastinating, or the person will not even receive a log, and I will have them question future me about that.

Comment: Have the program run as a user different from you.

Comment: @RaymondChen What would that achieve? I'd still have access to the data, no?

Comment: 1) get someone else to write the program and not give you the source code and it becomes a lot easier 2) can't you even trust yourself not forge logs in a system you wrote specifically to help yourself? It's possible, even likely that cognitive behavioural therapy would be a better way to solve the problem...

Comment: @DaveRandom You're correct, it seems rather extreme, but this is exactly what I do when I lie to my friends about how productive I am when I'm not. Except I forge words rather than logs. I'm already seeing a therapist, and you are totally correct that it's better, but it's a long term solution, which is something that takes time. This has the potential of being helpful in the short term while setting the long term right.

Comment: The program is run as another user and updates a file accessible only to that other user.

Comment: @RaymondChen http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc470670(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: I don't see how that is at all relevant. That's talking about TFS version control locks. I was referring to standard files in the file system, unrelated to TFS.

Comment: Sorry, I should probably check my sources before arrogantly just pasting whatever. My point is that you can easily remove another users lock. Looking quickly around i see several articles covering the topic, for instance http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the content of the program doesn't matter that much but you want to assure that the timestamp and content of the log can't be forged. I suggest writing the log to some external site where you can put data to but not delete from.

Writing false values to the log can only be prevented by having a log which progresses by time. For example, if you hide expenses from your bank account you'll run into problems because future balances will be lower than expected.

For short pieces of information like your account balance, just write it to some public site like Twitter. AFAIK it's not possible to send twitter messages like there were sent some time before.

For more complex data like the progress of a software development project push your changes with a version control system like git to a remote repo where you can't delete or overwrite history.

**Update:** As you explained in the comments you want to log dinstinct data on your computer that could be forged to anything. IMHO it's virtually impossible for you to write a program on your own which runs on your own computer with root but cannot be controlled. The only kind of software that is somehow similar to your request is DRM software that is calling home to prevent software "piracy". You need a binary program written by somebody else or with the source code deleted. It would need some kind of encrypted and obfuscated network communication which you can't understand.

I think there is not much hope for you using this approach. Better learn to control yourself and not answer random questions by strangers on Stackoverflow, ehem.

Comment: The bit on putting the data on the net is good, thanks for this part.
However writing the data to the site can be tricky if I could just tamper with the sender-client, making it send "oh so productive" all the time.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of data/measurement/... you want to provide to the log?

Comment: Offtopic, but sure. I want it to monitor which applications are running (they will be grouped into categories like "work", or "games", "writing", "personal project" or "internet" (which could be split into "work internet", "reddit", "facebook", "others" or something like that) ). The person on the other end will then receive a daily report of how much time i spend in each category.

Comment: After mulling over the input you have given me here (which again, I appreciate very much!), I've come up with the following: AES encryption (OTP can be cleartext attacked, and assymetric keys would be overenginering). Hardcode the key into the listener-application, which then encrypts the log with the key and datetime as nuance. Uploads the logs to a webservice. This is programmer proof, unless said programmer knows their way around assembly. Surely something can be done to prevent it to appear as cleartext in a hexeditor. I'll mark your answer as the answer, since you've been much helpful.